# Unable to activate windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, 32-vs-64-bit

When I right click computer, click properties, then click activate now I get the following error message:

The Windows 7 Product Key you typed is invalid for activation.

I already typed the product key that came with my computer during installation of a new version of windows.

How do I activate windows?

Here is the back story, so you don't make suggestions on things I already tried. I have a dell that came with windows 7 pro 64 bit. This is going to be a point of sale (POS) machine. The POS software can only work with 32 bit windows. But because of previous experience, I was going to just install a fresh copy of windows 7 pro 32 bit using the same key. This has worked for me before just a few months ago. This particular machine didn't come with a windows product key sticker like all other computers I have ever seen. Previously I was able to use the PID that was on the sticker but since it wasn't there this time, I downloaded a key finder application to get it out of the registry. This is the product key I am using.

Doing my searching on the internet I was informed of the possibility that there are actually two keys that come with an OEM machine. The key that is used for the factory install and a key that is on the sticker. Since I don't have a sticker, could this be the problem?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called MS and they were willing to activate one of the 13 computers I have this problem with. I called Dell and was directed to a 'First Response' team that sent me a Dell OEM windows 32bit DVD. When using this to install windows it automatically activates windows. Apparently this is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  They use one key to set them all up and pre-activate them, and then give you a different key.  Often these OEM factory keys are banned from activation by Microsoft.

Dell may not have provided any key, and instead just gave you a (pre-keyed/pre-activated) recovery partition or disk set you're supposed to use.

Call Microsoft; activation support is always free.  If they can't just get it activated for you, then they will at least be able to provide options/suggestions to obtain a proper key.

In the activation wizard choose to activate by phone, and it will provide the closest MS activation support number.

Comment: I called MS and after doing a little troubleshooting they were willing to give me another key that will activate.  The problem is, I ordered 13 computers from Dell that all have the same problem and MS was only willing to give me one key.

Comment: I called Dell and they have a "first response" team that I managed to get to.  They asked me to use their program to get the product key because it should find the actual key they used.  I did that with a second computer that I unpacked and it found the same exact key as the one my program found with the first computer.  She said that if this didn't fix the problem she would send me a CD with windows 7 pro 32bit that will install without having to use a key at all.  I will post back with the answer to the problem.

Comment: By the way, since that second computer had the same key, that is confirmation to me that they use the same key for many systems and that key cannot be used to active with MS.  Dell activates them in the factory.

Comment: I called MS and they were willing to activate one of the 13 computers I have this problem with.  I called Dell and was directed to a 'First Response' team that sent me a Dell OEM windows 32bit DVD.  When using this to install windows it automatically activates windows.  Apparently this is the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Also, If it is a DELL Laptop, remove the battery to see the sticker. The newer models don't have the sticker on the bottom of the laptop anymore cause the chance it gets dammaged.